# Datetime formatting with editor template MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

I want to format the DateTime displayed in TextBoxes without the time and to this format: 01 Jan, 2011 instead of the default 01/01/2011 for both display and edit scenarios.

I am already using the following template for DateTime in order to use datepicker. Can I somehow include formatting here?

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<System.DateTime?>" %>
<%: Html.TextBox("",ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue, new { @class = "text-box single-line" }) %>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

is `ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue` a datetime object?

to get the format you want out of a DateTime object use the following:

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
var formattedDate = now.ToString("dd MMM, yyyy");
```

this should work

```
<%= 
var theDate = Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.ToString("dd MMM, yyyy") : DateTime.Now.ToString("dd MMM, yyyy");


Html.TextBox("", theDate, new { @class = "text-box single-line" }) %>
```

The reason you are getting an error when you call `Model.ToString("dd MMM, yyyy")` is because it's a Nullable object, and it's [ToString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9hd15ket.aspx) method doesn't accept any parameters.  The value of the model is a DateTime object, which does accept parameters.

Comment: I can't do the formatting in the view like that because of the template I'm using.

Comment: can you set the value on the template, and then output it in the view?

Comment: Tried it like Darin suggested but I get the error I mentioned in my comment to his solution.

Answer (score 5):

```
<%= Html.TextBox("",  Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.ToString("dd MMM, yyyy") : "", new { @class = "text-box single-line" }) %>
```

or better yet on the view model:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd MMM, yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime? Foo { get; set; }
```

Comment: I get an error with the first one: No overload for method .ToString accepts one argument. I will have to change my view model to use the second one so I will get back in a bit.

Comment: @Tsarl, oh I didn't notice you were using a nullable DateTime. In this case you will need to test whether the model has a value, but personally I would recommend the second approach.

Comment: Thanks again Darin. You and Jason were both very helpful and gave me correct answers at about the same time. I marked his answer as the accepted one just because he has lower reputation than you :)

Comment: I too have date formating with Editor Templates that is not working for me. Posted here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18415653/mvc-4-editor-template-for-displaying-time-in-hhmm-format